# EnvDTE Project separate C# Project from solution project

Tags: c#, vsix, envdte

I know it sounds weird but I want to achieve  the following:
I´m writing on a VSIX extension that reads all my files that are included in a normal project or in the solution itself.
To access solution files or solution folders Microsoft organizes them also in the DTE project collection.
Look at the following example:

[image: Test solution]

So you can see, that in my solution there are 3 files: two solution files and one project item file.

Now take a look when I access the DTE project collection:

[image]

As you can see the "projects" in the solution have no FullName.
In my extension I need to differ normal projects and "solution projects" and the only way I found to do this is to check if the FullName property is null.
So I know this is a horrible solution, but do you know better ways to do that?
AND: Are solution files or items always located in the root directory where the .sln file is located?

greetings
Nico

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the DTE project collection, try moving up to the DTE [Solution interface instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution.aspx).

As you can see from the API, the fullname property is found there, as well as the collection of projects.

[Here's an example:](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014012.aspx)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

namespace Company.MyVSPackage
{
   // Only load the package if there is a solution loaded
   [ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]
   [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
   [InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
   [Guid(GuidList.guidMyVSPackagePkgString)]
   public sealed class MyVSPackagePackage : Package
   {
      public MyVSPackagePackage()
      {
      }

      protected override void Initialize()
      {
         base.Initialize();

         ShowSolutionProperties();
      }

      private void ShowSolutionProperties()
      {
         SVsSolution solutionService;
         IVsSolution solutionInterface;
         bool isSolutionOpen;
         string solutionDirectory;
         string solutionFullFileName;
         int projectCount;

         // Get the Solution service
         solutionService = (SVsSolution)this.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));

         // Get the Solution interface of the Solution service
         solutionInterface = solutionService as IVsSolution;

         // Get some properties

         isSolutionOpen = GetPropertyValue<bool>(solutionInterface, __VSPROPID.VSPROPID_IsSolutionOpen);
         MessageBox.Show("Is Solution Open: " + isSolutionOpen);

         if (isSolutionOpen)
         {
            solutionDirectory = GetPropertyValue<string>(solutionInterface, __VSPROPID.VSPROPID_SolutionDirectory);
            MessageBox.Show("Solution directory: " + solutionDirectory);

            solutionFullFileName = GetPropertyValue<string>(solutionInterface, __VSPROPID.VSPROPID_SolutionFileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Solution full file name: " + solutionFullFileName);

            projectCount = GetPropertyValue<int>(solutionInterface, __VSPROPID.VSPROPID_ProjectCount);
            MessageBox.Show("Project count: " + projectCount.ToString());
         }
      }

      private T GetPropertyValue<T>(IVsSolution solutionInterface, __VSPROPID solutionProperty)
      {
         object value = null;
         T result = default(T);

         if (solutionInterface.GetProperty((int)solutionProperty, out value) == Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK)
         {
            result = (T)value;
         }
         return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Credit: Our friend [Carlos Quintero](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/) was responsible for the code above.